# When to remove college leadership positions from CV/resume?

Tags: job-search, cv

This easily could be moved to the Workplace site, but I ask it here because I am in grad school and it's relevant to me finding internships, jobs, and/or academic positions.

**When is it time, or is it ever time, to remove college leadership positions from one's CV or resume?**

I was captain of a varsity athletic team in college and president of a social fraternity. Given only that, I could easily see someone saying "big deal, how does that show me you can write my software/prove this theorem/etc." However, in grad school, I have been president of my department's grad student association and started a popular journal group in my department (to list things that could be bullet-ed). I assume my adviser would also likely highlight similar leadership activities within our research group in any professional recommendation.

The reason I ask this question is primarily because I think those positions show a behavioral theme or track record. In all positions (other than the reading group, obviously), I was elected by my peers, and I can name specific accomplishments associated with each. Even if I am looking for research positions, I imagine that leadership/entrepreneurial spirit is a desired quality (?). Maybe I'm completely off-base. Hence my question. If relevant, I am within a decade of my undergrad.

So should I draw attention to those roles on my CV or website?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest removing them as soon as you stop being a student or reach your late 20s, whichever comes first.  Keeping that stuff on there too long may cause hiring managers and others to view you as stuck in your past and possibly adolescent.

Comment: I can see reasons why that would be the case (namely temporal relevance), but could you please elaborate on your thoughts?

Comment: Okay.  I've added another sentence which I hope will help clarify my thinking.